# Specific questions regarding the group action $G \times \mathcal{S}(G) \to \mathcal{S}(G)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, group-actions

Problem statement:

> Let $G$ be any group and recall $\mathcal{S}(G)$ denotes the set of subgroups of $G$. Let $G \times \mathcal{S}(G) \to \mathcal{S}(G)$ be given by $$g \cdot H = gHg^{-1}$$ Prove that this is an action. Prove that $stab_G(H) = N(H)$ the normalizer of $H$ and for which groups $G$ is this action transitive?

---

1. Let $e \in G$ be the identity element. Then we have $$e \cdot H = eHe^{-1} = eHe = H$$ Let $g,k \in G$ then we have $$g \cdot (k \cdot H) = g \cdot (kHk^{-1}) = gkHk^{-1}g^{-1} = gkH(gk)^{-1} = gk \cdot H$$ Thus $g \cdot H = gHg^{-1}$ is an action.

---

2. Now, the normalizer of $H$ is defined to be $$N(H) = \{g \in G \mid gHg^{-1} = H \}$$ The stabilizer of $H$ in $G$ is given by $$\text{stab}_G(H) = \{g \in G \mid g \cdot H = H \} = \{ g \in G \mid gHg^{-1} = H \}$$ Hence by inspection of these definition we conclude they are equal.

---

3. This action is transitive only for abelian groups. This is because any subgroup of an abelian group is normal and hence for any $H \in \mathcal{S}(G)$ we have $$gHg^{-1} = H\ \forall g \in G$$ Thus, $\forall H \in \mathcal{S}(G)$, $\exists g \in G$ such that $$g \cdot H = gHg^{-1} = H$$.

---

How does this look? Particularly parts $2$ and $3$. Part $2$ just seemed too simple and for part $3$ I believe I am correct but could be overlooking something or missing some nuance.

Comment: If I were grading this I would probably expect part (1) to include a proof of well-definedness, i.e., that the operation in question really does have the correct codomain.

Comment: @JBL, thanks for your perspective. I always forget about well-definition. What should I be on the look out for to suggest that well-definition is something I should prove? Should I consider proving that whenever I am given a mapping and have to show it has some property? I.e., is an action, is surjective, is a homomorphism, etc.. Conversely are there any cirumstances (aside from the problem explicitly stating the mapping in question is well-defined) where I would be confident that I don't need to show well-definition?

Comment: Well I would say that any time it is not obvious that the thing is defined where it's supposed to be and maps things where they're supposed to go, one should prove that it does.  Unfortunately what's obvious is context-dependent: if I were speaking to other math professors, I would treat the well-definedness of this particular map as obvious, but not for students in a first course in group theory.  As a student, I think it's better to err on the side of being careful.

Comment: (And ditto for all the other properties you mention.)

Answer (score 2):

Parts 1 and 2 are correct, but part 3 is totally wrong. I don't think you have the correct definition of *transitive*.

Comment: Hmm the definition I am working with is an action is transitive if there exists $g \in G$ such that for all $x,y \in X$ we have $$g \cdot x = y$$ In this case we have $g \cdot H = H$ so in other words there exists a $g \in G$ so that each element (subgroup of $G$) of $\mathcal{S}(G)$ equals itself. Can you point me towards where that is incorrect? Is it the case that $x$ and $y$ must be distinct?

Comment: Transitive means that you can get from any $x$ to any $y$ via the action of some group element $g$. What you have described is pretty much the opposite of that: for the subgroups of an abelian group (each normal, as you correctly noted), conjugation by any group element returns the same subgroup. In other words, starting at one subgroup, you can't get anywhere via this group action!

Comment: @SammyBlack, Okay I see. Thanks for the clarification. I misinterpreted it as $x,y \in X$ meaning that ANY $x$ and $y$ even $x = y$. So, given that we want to think of a group whose subgroups are such that we can find any subgroup $J <G$ from conjugating another subgroup $H < J$ so that $gHg^{-1} = J$? Would this be something like groups of prime order? Whose sylow p-subgroups are conjugate to one another by the second sylow theorem?

Comment: $x$ is allowed to equal $y$, that's not the issue. You have the order of quantifiers wrong. You said "an action is transitive if there exists $g \in G$ such that for all $x,y \in X$ we have $g \cdot x = y$." That is wrong. The correct definition is "an action is transitive if for all $x, y \in X$, there exists $g \in G$ such that $g \cdot x = y$." Note the difference in the order of quantifiers.